# SQL to find the period of time when an event occured the most

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider a SQL Server 2012 table which essentially records who (member) borrowed which book at which date in a library. The example is contorted.

- member_id int (foreign key to member table)
- book_id int (foreign key to book table)
- borrowed_date datetime

Is it possible to write a SQL query which will return the time period, let's say three months, when a given book was borrowed the most?

My efforts started and ended at `group by` the `book_id`, just not able to wrap my head around it.

Comment: 1) SQL can do a lot (asking is sth possible is silly) 2) Create sample data http://sqlfiddle.com 3) Share desired output 4) Show research effort and share your attempt

Comment: @lad2025 will do. thx.

Comment: hint:   Group by TimePeriod.

Comment: Please give some information about the time periodes you want to cover. You won't be able to cover **any** periode. If you say "3 months" do the start always with the first of the month or somewhere. The information you give is just not enough...

Comment: @TabAlleman wonderful, group by timeperiod having the most count. Think that should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a query which will give you the quarter in which the greatest number of times a book was borrowed.  The inner query returns a temporary table consisting of each quarter in which a given book (e.g. `book_id=5` here) was borrowed.  I then `SELECT` the single record which has the highest number of times where the book was borrowed.

```
SELECT t.theDate, t.theCount
FROM
(
    SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(borrowed_date), '-', QUARTER(borrowed_date)) AS theDate,
        COUNT(*) AS theCount
    FROM table
    WHERE book_id = 5
    GROUP BY CONCAT(YEAR(borrowed_date), '-', QUARTER(borrowed_date))
) t
ORDER BY t.theCount DESC
LIMIT 1
```